# Telerik RadGrid row data to populate GridEditableItem column

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a telerik radgrid with a hyperlink in one of the columns in edit mode. I want to have the text of the hyperlink set to the page title of the page it links to without creating a hidden field for this. I get this title from a database call which I pass the ID of the current row in the grid that is being edited.  Since the ItemDataBound method always does the binding of the GridEditableItem *before* the actual row itself, the MasterTableView does not contain the ID I need until the next iteration.

The ugly solution I came up with was to keep a reference to the hyperlink and populate it on the very next iteration when the ID is now availible on the grid.

I seem to think there is a better solution!

```
protected void grid_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        link = ((e.Item as GridEditableItem)["myHyperlink"].Controls[1] as HyperLink);
        go1 = true;
    }

    if(go2)
    {

        string myID = grid.MasterTableView.Items[grid.Items.Count - 1].GetDataKeyValue("myID").ToString();
        string pageId= PoolAgent.getPageId(Int32.Parse(myID));
        link.Text = pageId;
        go2 = false;
        go1 = false;
    }

    if (go1)
        go2 = true;
```

aspx:

```
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="myID" UniqueName="myID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="true">
               </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn EditFormColumnIndex="2" UniqueName="myHyperlink" HeaderText="Link:" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" Display="False" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Hyperlink ID="KeyManagerLink" Runat="server" NavigateUrl='' onclick="popupwindow(this.href, 'popupwindow', 1150, 500); return false;"></asp:Hyperlink>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: The "page titles" are just strings in a database that are populated, they are not related to the URLS or page titles

Comment: can you not set the Title attribute in the header of each of the pages and if not then if you are reading it from a table why not just capture the values in a List or a Session and assign the Page.Title = to that variable that you have stored.. your code there shows nothing to do with the Page.Title.. show the .aspx mark-up as well

Comment: There's actually only one page that the hyperlink links to with the ID as a parameter, so I don't think that would work. The aspx markup is very large and confidential, and I'm not sure what else is relevant other than the GridEditableItem inside the radgrid.

Comment: I am not sure what can be so confidential about aspx markup especially when you probably only need to show how you have the ItemTemplate setup in the markup.. if there is information like connection strings, passwrods, ects just put in dummy data.. we are not interestedin that.. only the logic and the way that you have declared certain attributes.. thanks

Comment: ItemTemplate markup added, thanks for following up :)